# Edit User Info Using Devise and Devise_Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, form-for, devise-invitable

I'm struggling with this issue for the past week or so, and I've tried everything I could think of so I need your help..! I'm using devise and devise invitable

I've created a page to edit user info like username, firstname, lastname...

```
# /controllers/settings_controllers.rb 
class SettingsController < ApplicationController   
  def info
    @user = current_user   
  end 
end

# /controllers/users_controllers.rb 
class UsersController < Devise::SessionsController   
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
end

# /views/settings/info.html.erb 
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> 
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %> 
<%= f.label :username %> 
<%= f.text_field :username %> 
<%= f.label :firstname %> 
<%= f.text_field :firstname %> 
.... 
<% button_value = "Update" %> 
<% end %>
```

My routes :

```
  devise_for :users ,:controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations' }
  resources :users, only: [:edit, :update]
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]                                          
    as :user do
      get 'user/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'    
      put 'user' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            
    end

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'aggregator#index'
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
    end

    get "users/new" => "users#new"
    get "users/:id" => "users#show"
  end
  match 'settings/info' => 'settings#info', :as => 'info'
```

When I try to update the form, I have the following error (my user id is 1) :

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/1"
```

**Edit**

So I've put `resources :users, only: [:edit, :update]` after `devise_for :users`, like suggested by @coletrain and error is gone. But it redirects to my profile `/users/1` when I want to be redirected to `/settings/info` and more importantly, it does not update my info...
My guess is that update method in users_controller is not reached.

Comment: Try moving your devise_for :users above resource: users

Comment: It's working - but it doest not update user info and it redirects me to users/1 when I want to be redirected to settings/info (redirect_to in users#update does not work)

Comment: In your controller update action change `@user = current_user` to `@user = User.find(current_user.id)`. After that write an if statement that upon success redirects to desire page or upon failure redirects back to edit page. Let me know if it works.

Comment: did it but it doesn't work - see edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the routes.rb: 
 add `put "users/:id" => "users#update"` inside `devise_scope :user do ... end` block.

Also:
 In user_controller update method, change `@user.update_attributes(user_params)` to  `@user.update_attributes(params["user"])`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think the simplest solution is this: Just use what devise gives you by default.

**Routes:**

```
devise_scope :user do

  get "account", to: "devise/registrations#edit"
  patch "account", to: "devise/registrations#update"
  put "account", to: "devise/registrations#update"
  delete "account", to: "devise/registrations#destroy"

end
```

/**views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb** #generated by devise
replace the path like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```

to this (because I named the routes "account" in this example)

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: account_path, html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```

**Note that you have to delete resource_name too**. Otherwise there will be routing problems after you committed changes